# Ubuntu - Grub menu won't show up anymore after low battery shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub, reboot, brightness

I have `dualboot`ed my MacBookAir and have been using my `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)` partition without any issue for a long time. Now when I restart my computer, the screen goes black and computer seems to turn off without prompting the `Grub` menu. Here is what I exactly did last time I had access to the Ubuntu partition:

- I turned the displays' brightness to 0 using `xrandr` for the second monitor and the relevant function key for the main (computer's) screen.
- I went away for a while with the computer still turned on (yes, no sleep mode)
- I couldn't restore the screen's brightness, as the computer actually ran out of battery. I put it to charging. It was off.
- Pressing on/off button didn't turn computer on at all. I had to press on/off button several seconds (like for forcing it to shut-down)
- Then I could turn it on by pressing on/off only once like usual
- Screen seemed normally bright with black background. Before displaying the grub menu, it goes black, brightness goes off and computer seems to be off.
- I always have to emulate the forced shutting down as described above prior to turn it on again.
- I turned it on on the mac boot menu (holding `Option` key)
- I could boot on `MacOSX` and shut down normally
- On reboot, the Grub menu still won't show up, screen and computer shut down as described before.
- I booted on a live-usb and re-installed grub following those steps without any issue or error: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd
- I rebooted
- The screen still goes off and the grub menu still doesn't appear.

Maybe it's related to `Ubuntu` shutting down with brightness set to 0, does it keep some configuration files for the brightness somewhere? I really don't know what to do and check from here. As a last redsort maybe I will try re-installing my `Ubuntu` from scratch.

---

### EDIT

Re-installing Ubuntu solved the issue. However, I couldn't reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Assuming this is just a brightness issue *and* that Ubuntu is the default (first) option at Grub, pressing Enter when at that "black screen" should boot Ubuntu albeit with the same brightness but now you should be able to open a TTY, login and revert the brightness settings.

Comment: I couldn't do that